# ¿Restringir dos décimas en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Buen día tengo mi siguiente consulta en mysql:

```
SELECT (viviendas / (SELECT num_vivi 
                     FROM fraccionamientos 
                     WHERE id=1) 
       ) * 100 as total 
FROM ingre_men, fecha_fin 
WHERE 
    fecha_fin= fecha_fin.fecha 
    AND id_fracc=1;
```

Como resultado me devuelve:

> 54.0131

Pero solo quiero que me devuelva 54.01
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.

Answer (score 9):

Puedes usar [TRUNCATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate), es este caso puedes definir el numero de decimales a mostrar al realizar la consulta (segundo parámetro definir `2`), ejemplos:

```
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(1.223,1)
        -> 1.2
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,2)
        -> 1.99
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,0)
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(-1.999,1)
        -> -1.9
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(122,-2)
       -> 100
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(10.28*100,0)
       -> 1028
```

> [TRUNCATE(X, D)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) Devuelve el número X, truncado a D decimales. Si
>   D es 0, el resultado no tiene punto decimal o parte fraccionaria. D
>   puede ser negativo para hacer que los dígitos D a la izquierda del
>   punto decimal del valor X se conviertan en cero.

---

Veo que como opción se menciona [FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) o `ROUND()`  pero en este caso el valor se podría redondear lo cual no es correcto.

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(1.999,2)
       -> 2.00

mysql> SELECT ROUND(1.999,2)
       -> 2.00
```

Comment: @SoyKrut esta me parece la respuesta mas acertada, ya que como menciona FORMAT() te redondeara el valor de salida

Answer (score 4):

Usa la función `FORMAT()` para indicar cual es la salida deseada; la que por dentro recibe el número a tratar y separado por una coma la indicas la cantidad de decimales que deseas muestre:

**EJEMPLO**

```
SELECT FORMAT(54.0131, 2);
```

Salida

> 54.01

Referencias:

- [Función `FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Sin embargo como bien me comentan para un caso como el siguiente

```
SELECT FORMAT(1.999, 2);
```

El resultado será

> 2.00

Por lo cual esta *solución* no se ajusta bien del todo a números cuyos decimales se aproximan al inmediato superior (considerando que los decimales sean 3 o mas y que además sean el mismo número)

Ejemplos:

```
SELECT FORMAT(1.888, 2);
```

Dará

> 1.89

Comment: Hola, si usas format() en este ejemplo: SELECT FORMAT(1.999,2); obtendrías 2 lo cual no es correcto.

Comment: tienes razón @Elenasys no me detuve a pensar en esos casos; en seguida elimino la respuesta

Comment: no la elimines solo agrega ese posible caso que no se cumple, creo que es buena información.

Comment: hecha la aclaración @Elenasys gracias por la observación

Answer (score 2):

Tiene la opción de utilizar `TRUNCATE()`

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(Valor, numDecimales);
```

Donde valor es lo que quiera devolver de la consulta y el numDecimales el número de decimales que desea, en este caso sería 2

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la función convert y la función round

ejemplo:

```
SELECT convert(ROUND(3.9844754, 2),float ) as cant
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo con:

```
select round(54.0131,2)
```

Comment: Hola Byro porque en la documentación menciona que SELECT ROUND(1.58); obtiene como resultado 2, cuando en realidad obtiene 1.58, tu sabes la razón? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: esto es porque `round()` redondea al numero siguientes si los decimales son mayor o igual a la mitad mientras que redonde a el numero mas bajo si es menor a la mitad. `1.58` redondeado es `2` si pones `1.49` es resultado sera `1`.

Comment: @Elenasys pero eso en el caso de no especificar la cantidad de decimales que quieres

Comment: @Elenasys exacto!